# How to compare two arrays and change the name if id matches?

Tags: javascript

I have a student array like below

```
student=[{id:1,name:'Sam',age:23},{id:2,name:'Jolia',age:23},{id:3,name:'Peter',age:23}]
```

And also I have another one which contains updated age values of some students like below for example

```
updated=[{id:2,age:25},{id:3,age:21}]
```

In this case I wanna find intersection by Id of these two arrays and change age values of student array with updated ones.

**Expected Result**

```
 student=[{id:1,name:'Sam',age:23},{id:2,name:'Jolia',age:25},{id:3,name:'Peter',age:21}]
```

values of id:2 and id:3 changed as updated includes those id values.

I tried to iterate two arrays by map but didn't work and didnt seem sensible to me.

```
updated.map(e=>{
   if(e.id==student.map(j=>{j.id})){
     e.age=j.age;
   }
 })
```

Comment: You do not want `map()`.  You want a normal `forEach` on the updated, and then a find/filter on the student list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let updated=[{id:2,age:25},{id:3,age:21}];
let student=[{id:1,name:'Sam',age:23},{id:2,name:'Jolia',age:23},{id:3,name:'Peter',age:23}];
student.forEach(e =>{
  let idx = updated.findIndex(u => u.id == e.id);
  if(idx >=0) {
      e.age = updated[idx].age;
  }
});

console.log(student);
```

You can use `forEach` instead of `map()` for this scenario. Iterate over all students and update age based on the update array if id matches. [`findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) returns the index of first element in the array that satisfies the provided testing function

Answer (score 1):

```js
var student=[{id:1,name:'Sam',age:23},{id:2,name:'Jolia',age:23},{id:3,name:'Peter',age:23}];
var updated=[{id:2,age:25},{id:3,age:21}];

updated.forEach(delta => {
  student.forEach(record => {
    if (delta.id === record.id) {
      record.age = delta.age;
      return false;
    }
  });
});

console.log(student);
```

You can use simple for each logic to iterate over each element to update them.  Returning false in the inner forEach will result in it terminating once a match has been made.

Comment: Yeah thanks for your solution but instead of iterating two loops nested do you have better approach?

Comment: Without the elements being objects with actual keys, there are going to be two iterations.  Either you are going to write the iterations, or you will use a find/filter approach, which is still two iterations, just you are not writing the second one